# How to change the font and size of the Chapters titles and numbers of Bjornstrup

Tags: fonts, sectioning, chapters, fncychap

This is a follow-up question to [Question about Bjornstrup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/questions-about-bjornstrup/36943#36943), where, in the answers, Gonzalo Medina posted a [short script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36943/25183) on how to change the background and numbers colors of a specific Chapter format.

The question I have now is: 
How can I change the font and size of the Chapters titles and numbers?
There should be some lines to change in the script but I don't know where ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font, font size and shape of the chapter numbers can be changed via:

```
\renewcommand{\CNoV}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont\small \itshape} % the number
```

The font selection is done here with `\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont`, which selects the Palatino font.

The chapter title can be change via:

```
\renewcommand{\CTV}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\Large \scshape}  % the title
```

Here, we used Helvetica as the font.

Put that into your preamble, and change to your likings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but I lose completely the "Bjornstrup" style that I had previously. Moreover, this does not allow me to change the font itself, does it? –

Comment: @Ben What do you mean by completely losing the Bjornstrup style? My answer shows how to change the size (`\small` and `Large` in my answer), and the shape of the font (`itshape` and `\scshape` in my answer).